# R : How can I minimize the function related to unknown parameter?

Tags: r, optimization, minimize

I want to make a function in R which minimizes the objective with unknown parameter. 
The exact equation is

```
Q_beta=min_{beta} sum_{i=1}^{i=n} || x_i - f(beta) ||^2
```

Here,  `||.||` means euclidean measure and I want to sum all `n` objects.
`x_i` is a vector and `f(beta)` is same dimension vector as `x_i`, and it contains unknown parameter `beta`.
In this case, I want to minimize summation of all `n` squared euclidean objective and I also want to know which `beta` minimizes them.

Can I make a function of this in R? what kind of function do I need to use?
Thank you.

Comment: It depends on your function `f`, but have a look at `?optimise` and `?optim`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
rm(list=ls())

lower <- -2 ## lower interval endpoint of possible betas
upper <- 2 ## upper interval endpoint
beta0 <- runif(1,lower,upper) ## true beta, randomly selected from interval
t <- seq(0,1,by=.01) ## grid of values that function is fit over
x <- beta0*t^2


## goal is to find beta0

f <- function(beta) beta*t^2
g <- function(beta) sum((x-f(beta))^2)


fit <- optimize(g,lower=lower,upper=upper)

## the following two should match
fit$minimum
beta0
```